# ¿Qué debe hacerse ante respuestas duplicadas y simultáneas?

Tags: discusión, respuesta, convenciones-sociales

He visto mucha documentación respecto a qué hacer cuando hay preguntas duplicadas, pero he buscado en Meta y no he visto información de qué hacer cuando hay respuestas duplicadas o prácticamente iguales.

La duda me ha saltado cuando estaba contestando [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/160455/no-se-puede-cambiar-un-caracter-con-charat): se me ha caído el wifi y al recargar la página he visto que ya habían contestado a la pregunta 3 personas.

Las 3 respuestas son prácticamente iguales, ya que los 3 al fin y al cabo acaban usando el `String.replace(" ", "%20");`.

La diferencia de tiempo de la respuesta es de 1 minuto entre cada una de las respuestas, por tanto lo más seguro es que mientras estaban redactando la respuesta los otros usuarios contestaran, con lo cual no parece que se hayan copiado unos de otros.

Ante esta situación de respuestas prácticamente iguales, ¿qué hago?

- ¿Borro mi respuesta? (En el caso de que haya contestado también)
- ¿Se vota solamente en positivo al que primero publicó la respuesta?
- ¿Se deja como está?

No es algo que moleste, simplemente que no me parece útil tener 3 respuestas iguales.

Comment: Es cierto, muchas veces buscando ayuda en la pagina uno espera encontrar diferentes soluciones y solo encuentra varias respuestas iguales. Lo mejor es que los autores modifiquen su respuesta para brindar algún aporte extra o la eliminen para evitar la redundancia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Me parece que estos casos deben celebrarse pues el hecho de que tres miembros de la comunidad hubiesen coincidido en dar prácticamente la misma respuesta es una maravilla.

Ahora bien, en términos de las acciones estándares del modelo del sitio en mi opinión deberían tratarse las tres respuestas de la siguiente forma

- primero, cada una de ellas votarlas como si no existieran las otras respuestas y si hiciera falta dejar un comentarios con una sugerencia de mejora o crítica constructiva.
- segundo, dejar un comentario o incluir en el comentario del punto anterior una mención jubilosa de la situación.

En cuanto a los autores de las respuestas

1. Si las otras respuestas son semejantes a la tuya,

   - si están bien redactadas y completas vótalas positivo. Nota: la medalla [espíritu deportivo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/63/sportsmanship) reconoce los que hacen esto al menos 100 veces.
   - si tiene cosas que mejorar, déjales un comentario
   - si sólo coinciden en el código y la respuesta carece de una explicación completa deja un comentario indicando el motivo.
   - si sólo coinciden en el código y la explicación no es clara o no se incluye, vótala negativo.
2. Si leyendo las otras respuestas te das cuenta de que tu respuesta puede diferenciarse de las otras mediante una edición, hazla.
3. Para prevenir votos negativos de los "distraídos" agrega una nota mencionando la situación.

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo pero luego depende de cada uno como actuar con su propia respuesta. Yo a veces si mi respuesta no es la aceptada y veo que no aporta nada nuevo la borro por no generar ruido, me gusta que cuando hay varias respuestas ofrezcan distintas soluciones y no la misma. Pero como digo es cosa de cada uno, no hay porqué borrarla.

Comment: En principio y como política personal, la mejor respuesta considero que siempr debería de tener más votoss, por ello trata siempre de que tu respuesta sea siempre la mejor, la más clara, la más concisa, la mejor ejemplificada, la más apta a cada tipo de aprendizaje, la que más referencias la respalden, y sobre todo, la que no deje lugar a dudas, y si no puedes hacer tu respuesta así, tal vez deberías de darle una oportunidad a los demás.